# nginx rewrite - files exist but are rewritten

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

i have a php app under `/path/`

everything that doesn't exist (files/directories) needs to be redirected to `/path/index.php`

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
  rewrite ^/path/(.+)$ /path/index.php last;
}
```

and everything works apart from the real files, for some reason .css files that exist are still redirected to the index ... eg `/path/CSS/style.css`

**UPDATE**

fixed with `rewrite ^/path/(.+)/$ /path/index.php last;` because all my urls that need to be re-written end with a trailing slash, but still confusing

nginx.conf

```
http {
 include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;  
 access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

 sendfile        on;

 keepalive_timeout  65;
 tcp_nodelay        on;

 gzip  on;
 gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

full site-enabled/file

```
server {
  listen  valueyourvote.org.nz:80;
  server_name  valueyourvote.org.nz valueyourvote.co.nz;

  if ($http_host != www.valueyourvote.org.nz) {
      rewrite  (.*)  http://www.valueyourvote.org.nz$1;
  }
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/valueyourvote.org.nz.access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/valueyourvote.org.nz.error.log;
  location / {
    root   /var/www/vote.incode.co.nz/;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
  }

  if (!-e $request_filename)
  {
    rewrite ^/supercity-2010/(.+)/$ /supercity-2010/index.php last;
  }


  # Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;

    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
  # concurs with nginx's one
  location ~ /\.ht {
     deny  all;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using "if" in nginx whenever possible - see ["If is evil"](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) on the nginx Wiki. For your usage, a better directive to use would be [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files).

As for the directives not working, you are testing for files outside of the scope of your "root" directive - i.e. nginx does not know where to look to see if those URIs are files!

Put a try_files directive inside your location block and that should work.

Comment: i tried `try_files` based on information here http://michaelshadle.com/2009/03/19/finally-using-nginxs-try-files-directive But it didn't help, maybe there is something funky going on elsewhere in the config, but its just a base install on ubuntu so they should be ok

Comment: If you could provide more of the nginx configuration perhaps we could find the bug :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
location [your_location]{
   try_files $uri $uri/ @w;
 }
location @w {
rewrite ^/path/(.+)$ /path/index.php last;
}
```